# Azure function fails with unhelpful error message of Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I've created an Azure function and tested it locally in Visual Studio without issue. I just published the function to Azure and now when I run it I get this error:

```
2019-11-26T20:41:11.822 [Error] Executed 'PullAffiliationsFunction' (Failed, Id=13a5b787-db22-4b04-96ba-f5718c36aa75)
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value
```

I don't have any parameters named value in my function.  I see no stack trace to give me more information about what is causing this error.  Did I miss a configuration setting somewhere?  I published directly from Visual Studio so I would expect it would publish everything.  How would you debug this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you get this exception as part of the `Executed` message, it's most likely thrown by your function code. Do you have the full log entry for that? It may include a stack trace as well.

The local settings and environment variables (from `local.settings.json`) actually do not automatically get pushed to Azure on publish.

I have seen this exception commonly when one may have forgotten to set an environment variable as an App Setting or a connection string. Did you set all the environment variables you used locally in your Azure function app through Application Settings or configuration in your app?

Comment: I have two functions that I loaded and only loaded environment variables for one of the functions.  When I loaded all the environment variables this error went away.  I still think the error message could actually name the variable that is missing instead of "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value"